# Mouse X & Y positions for get_rect.collidepoint in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a click event in PyGame but I am facing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

The code:

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if mouse_pressed[0] and play_btn.get_rect().collidepoint(mouse_pos[0],
                                                         mouse_pos[1]):
    print "Mouse clicked play"
```

The button...

```
play_btn = button("PLAY NOW", 210, 150, 300, 80, white, grey)
```

Comment: `pygame` doesn't have a  built-in `button` class, so we can't answer your question unless you [edit] it and add the class definition for the one your code is using. Hint: I suspect the problem is you need to add a `get_rect()` method to it.

Comment: Problem solved, tried another way.

Comment: Then please delete your question if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided, `button` doesn't return anything. It returns `None`.

According to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190253/pygame-button-cant-seek-in-this-data-source) your function `button` looks like this:

```
def button(btn_txt_img,posx,posy):
    btn_txt_img = pygame.image.load(("/Users/wolf/Desktop/python/img/",btn_txt_img,".png")).convert_alpha()
    btn_txt_img_hover = pygame.image.load(("/Users/wolf/Desktop/python/img/",btn_txt_img,"_hover.png")).convert_alpha()

    if((w_size[0]/3.3)+btn_txt_img.get_rect().width > mouse_pos[0] > (w_size[0]/3.3) and posy+btn_txt_img.get_rect().height > mouse_pos[1] > posy):
        return main_screen.blit(btn_txt_img_hover, [(w_size[0]/3.3),posy,btn_txt_img.get_rect().width,btn_txt_img.get_rect().height])
    else:
        return main_screen.blit(btn_txt_img, [(w_size[0]/3.3),posy,btn_txt_img.get_rect().width,btn_txt_img.get_rect().height])
    pygame.display.update()
```

Blitting works directly on the object and therefore returns `None`. Since your function returns whatever `main_screen.blit...` returns, it'll also return `None`